# How to stop a static resource loaded from a LWC as a Quick Action from impacting other LWCs as Quick Actions?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, cache

I have two Quick Actions that leverage LWC components on the Opportunity flexi-page.

In my first LWC, I have a custom CSS from an imported static resource that gets loaded in a renderedCallBack.

The LWC renders fine and has the correct CSS. However, I notice that when I close that LWC and click the next Quick Action, which leverages a LWC which ***doesn't*** import any static resource, the CSS from the first LWC is also displaying on the second LWC.

How can I prevent this from happening? It seeems that I need to programmatically query the entries in the cache and then delete the matching cache when the first LWC is closed but what is odd is that I don't see any entries in the Application Panel / Cache Storage in the browser.

Another option, I guess, would be to do a hard-reload of the page in JavaScript at the point that the LWC is closed. But that would then be subpar from a UX perspective because in Lightning, it would add another 2 seconds or so before the opportunity page is re-rendered.

Comment: Are these LWCs using light DOM?

Comment: The better question might be: why are you importing a static CSS instead of using standard CSS files?

Comment: (I assumed there was a reason, such as the CSS file is too large to be handled as part of the LWC, but perhaps I should have not made that assumption!)

Comment: I should have been clearer, it's because I want to make the modal wider. As per https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344409/spring-21-lwc-quick-actions-how-to-change-modal-width, this seems the recommended way to do this because I couldn't override the slds-modal container with CSS in the component.